# Peak to get header values of CSV in R

Tags: r

I would like to set `colClasses` programmatically based on text in the header, but first I need to peak into the csv to get the header names that will then be used to set `colClasses`. How would I go about peaking? Is there a way of doing this without loading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something along the lines:

```
header <- read.table(csv.filename,sep=";",
                     nrows=3,header=T)

col.classes <- sapply(foo,class)
data <- as.data.frame(read.table(csv.filename,
                             sep=";",
                             header=T,
                             colClasses=col.classes))
```

or equivalent with `read.csv`

```
header <- read.csv(csv.filename,sep=";",
                     nrows=3,header=T)

col.classes <- sapply(foo,class)
data <- read.csv(csv.filename,
                             sep=";",
                             header=T,
                             colClasses=col.classes)
```